# Suggestions on posting huge string to web service

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

Below is my array :

```
var.child.Cars1 = { name:null,operation:0,selected : false}
```

Now in above array,**selected property** represent **check/uncheck status of checkbox** and **i am posting above array to web service(WCF) as string using json.stringify.**

Above array contains 2000 - 4000 records and now user can check/uncheck checkboxes.

Now consider there are 4000 records in above array in which there are 2000 records which are checked and 2000 records are unchecked and in my web service i am processing only those records which are checked.I remove records with selected value as false.

Now as due to 4000 records its a huge json string and because of that i get error from web service end :

```
  Error :  (413) Request Entity Too Large
```

Now reason why i am not filtering out records with selected as flase is because it will create lots of overhead on client browser and can even hang browser so right now i am doing it on server side.

So my question is that i should filter out records with selected as false on client side and then post 2000 records only or what i am doing is the right way.

I have some question in my mind that posting such huge json string will again take some times and filtering out records with selected as false will also put lots of overhead on browser.

So i am not sure i am doing wrong or right.

Can anybody please guide me for this???

Comment: Filtering this out on client should not hang browser I think, maybe you are doing something wrong (inefficient) when filtering in javascript. Anyway, from two possibilities (filter on client or send useless data on server and filter there) I will always choose filter on client. Same is true in reversed direction.

Comment: @Evk :Ok if i consider that it will not hang client browser then still it would take lots of time for this kind of filtering.consider if records are like 7000- 8000 then still you would prefer this on client side?

Comment: Well I would never post array with 8000 items to server unless absolutely have to (but cannot imagine such situation). You said items represent checkbox state. I don't think user can manually check or uncheck 8000 items at once. Mosy likely you present him a list with 8000 items (which you should page at least) and he changes some. So then - only post what has been changed to server, not all items.

Comment: @Evk :I present user with 8000 item list and i have given functionality like filter and check/uncheck all option using which user can select/unselect all items.with filter user can filter items from those 8000 items.now consider if user select all items with the help of checkall button then ??

Comment: Then notify server that all items are checked without listing them. Server knows how to get full list of items.

Comment: @Evk:What if items from 2000 - 7000 are checked and 2000 - 3000 records contains operation property as 1 and 3000 - 7000 records contains operation property as 0

Comment: @Learning, you can add and ID (or use the name property), and send only the ID as a array [2000,2001,2002]. This will reduce the size considerably. Alternatively you could encode the original array in base64 and send it in chunks of fixed size. But this will make your api more complex. I recommend to reduce the size if you can

Comment: You can also sen several ajax request grouping records, 0-1000, 1001-2000, etc, and cache them in server. How long is your json?, until 10-12mb you probably won't have problems

Comment: @pedrofb : how to reduce the size??

Comment: As I commented, send only the imprecindible data: an array with IDs or names and only for changes

Comment: See [Converting large numbers from binary to decimal and back in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334494/converting-large-numbers-from-binary-to-decimal-and-back-in-javascript)

Comment: You should really maintain 'dirty' flag, and only send those which have changed.... Even showing a user 4,000 checkboxes doesn't seem like a logical thing to do, does the user really need to pay attention to 4,000 pieces of information at once? Studies indicate we can manage about 7....

Comment: An alternative would be to use AJAX to send each checkbox values as it changes. Then you would only ever send one change at a time, as the user presumably can't check 4,000 checkboxes in any small period of time....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if you start running in to the large request size issues like this, it is a good opportunity to look at ways to optimize instead of override. A lot of people have tried providing ways to circumvent the problem, but have not provided insight as to ways that don't circumvent it, but instead improve upon the design to be more lightweight.

Here are some possibilities:

Have you considered paging the request(s)? This would allow you to asynchronously load the data on the client as needed, thus preventing the requests from taking too long, improving the responsiveness of the website, and reducing any burdens on both the client and server memory wise. You can preemptively load the data as a user scrolls, and if need be, provide some sort of entertainment/feedback to the user if the process is taking too long, so they know there's more data being loaded.

Have you considered changing the names of the properties to be shorter, and less descriptive, reducing the footprint of the object itself? For example:

Your current model:

`{ name:null,operation:0,selected : false}`

A simplified model:

`{ n: null, o: 0, s: false }`

An approach such as this will make it harder to read the JSON itself, but JSON isn't meant solely to be read by people, it's meant to serialize data; although, this can be overcome by documenting your model. Doing it this way may help to reduce your data being sent by up to 30%.

I cannot provide a complete approach to the solution because you will have to ask yourself a lot of hard questions as to what you're trying to achieve, who will be consuming the data, and how is the best way to get there.

In addition, I would strongly consider questioning why a process would require a user to interact with 2000+ records at once. I am not trying to criticize, but say you need to take a critical look at the business process behind what you're trying to achieve because there may be serious issues with repetitiveness, stress on the user and more, which would greatly affect how your application will be effective and useful to the end-user. As an example, is there ways you can break up the task in to smaller, less tedious blocks so that the end user doesn't stare at 4000 checkboxes for 2 hours?

This may not be the answer you're looking for as it opens up a huge number of additional questions, but hopefully it will help you start to formulate questions which help shape the final answer.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Very very nice explanation.I really appreciate 
your explanation.Thank you so much and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: You're welcome. A lot of the time, we're under pressure to get things done quickly, and it's hard not to try and hack together something, but it's important to step back at times, especially in situations like this. If you need further help in trying to pin down a good solution, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Yeah definetely i will.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix might be increasing the servers allowed content length. This is approximately what that would look like.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
       <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
       </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: If you want to cripple this web server

Answer (score 3):

It is preferable to filter data on the client side provided you do not impact the UI thread (lockup the browser).  Posting too much data can cause issues depending on what you are trying to do and the network speed of the end user.  That being said, sometimes you just have to post large data.  I'm not sure how large those 4000 records are, but if it's only text then it can't be too large.

Since your issue is that the WCF site is responding back with the 413 response, that's where you are having your max size issue.  According to the [WCF documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.transportbindingelement.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.110).aspx), the maximum allowable message size that can be received by default is 65,536 bytes.  Obviously, that is below what you are attempting to send.

This is what you need to update in your WCF service.  Sample below is for 10MB, but increase to whatever makes sense for your data.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <!-- Measured in Bytes -->
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">    <!-- 10 MB-->
        <readerQuotas ... />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you begin getting a 404.13 HTTP status code, then you also need to update your web.config to allow longer max sizes, but set it to whatever size makes the most sense for your application.

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- Add this section for file size... -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- Measured in Bytes -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />  <!-- 1 GB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <!-- Measured in kilobytes -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />   <!-- 1 GB-->
</system.web>
```

Comment: I need to set readerquotas setting both on wcf and client side right?

Comment: I need to set only ReaderQuotas on both client and wcf end or other configurations are also there to make this work??

Answer (score 1):

1. Save json value as file
2. Upload the json file (while getting unique filename)
3. Call your WCF method with filename passed instead of json value
4. Read the data from the file passed to the method

Answer (score 1):

You should filter on the client, as you don't know how slow the connection to the server might be. Sending unneeded data is likely to be slower than filtering it first.

If filtering the data is hanging the browser, then you can get around this problem by using a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using GET method so this is not working because Get method URL maximum character limit is 2,083 character. so please use post method in web service using Json object.

Comment: My call to web service is Post call

Comment: Passing json object as string

Comment: var arraylist = []; 
var jsonList = JSON.stringify(arraylist);
var data = { list: jsonList };
you can pass data like this using post method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set maxRequestLength in config.These settings worked for me to upload 750 mb.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

maxRequestLength maximum is 2097151, If you try set more error occurred.
And [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) says ;

> The default size is 4096 KB (4 MB).

Answer (score 1):

Filtering on a client side should not create a huge overhead and it should be possible to sustain the resulting `json` string size within the request limits.

Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is pretty straightforward to filter to only selected/checked elements and map to only required operations:

```
var filteredCars = _.where(cars, {selected: true});
//an assumption that operation is a unique car id
var operations = _.map(filteredCars, function(car){ return {id: car.operation};});
```

Please see this [extended JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shcdgfbk/7/) for filtering with the similar array size and some stats alongside.

I would however doubt, presenting 4k checkboxes in a single UI screen, would be any user friendly?