# Generate float in range from HEX hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

How to generate (in JavaScript or Node.JS) float in range from 0.00000000 - 100.00000000 from given long HEX hash? For example SHA-256?

I am open to solutions with `crypto` library because I using it to generate given hash :)

Comment: quite complicated, but possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447807/javascript-parse-string-to-long/46583936#46583936

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not concerned about precision loss, and your hex strings are of a fixed length (as with SHA-256), you could simply map from one value space to the other:

```
function hexStrToFraction(hexStr) {
    // Expresses a hexadecimal string of N characters as a fraction
    // of one above its maximum possible value (16^N).
    // Returns a number between 0 and 1.
    return parseInt(hexStr, 16) / Math.pow(16, hexStr.length);
}

function sha256ToPercent(sha256) {
    return 100 * hexStrToFraction(sha256);
}
```

Note that the precision loss is high enough to render the majority of a SHA-256 redundant:

```
var a = 'b2339969703a8c4b49e4a5c99cca6013ed455f52d06f8f03adb927aee7d9c3c0'
var b = 'b2339969703a8c8b8504772b860b9ed2cb6aa0186ff6750981e7ccd5344e4bf1'
//                     ^ differences start here
hexStrToFraction(a) === hexStrToFraction(b) // evaluates true
```

Comment: I don't care about precision loss that much. Thanks. This working

Comment: Could you explain your code please? Maybe some documentation that `hexStrToDecimal` returns a value between 0 and 1 and how division by 16 to the power of `maxLength` helps with that.

Comment: I guess maxLength is not really needed. The hexadecimal string will always be 64 characters in size, so you may as well use the size of hexStr itself (presuming it contains *just* hexadecimal characters).

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes - now edited as suggested. My original thinking with specifying `maxLength` was to be visually explicit about the constant length requirement, but on reflection the degree of precision loss makes the explicitness somewhat pointless.

Comment: Is there way to not loss so much?

Comment: You could try a library for increasing precision such as [bignumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). Though you'd be tied into using it for any subsequent arithmetic that requires high precision. What are you planning to use this value for? It might be that there's a more convenient value format for your purposes than using a single number.