# How to convert a string of big number to integer?

Tags: javascript, string, scientific-notation

JavaScript converts all the big numbers into scientific notation.
`eg: '90938498237058927340892374089'` this string when converted to an integer will come out like this scientific notation '`9.093849823705893e+28`'.

How can I convert the data type from String to an Integer and avoiding the scientific notation?

Comment: Going to need a big number library

Comment: Your number is way too big. I would suggest using a library like this: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: check out [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), maybe this is what are looking for.

Comment: programming languages have limits as to how big of a number they can store as an integer. you might want to look up what that limit is.

Answer (score 2):

In JS all the numbers are treated as floating-point so in end, they end up with precision you can use try `BigInt('90938498237058927340892374089')` which will give you exact number from string to number.
apart from this, you can also have a look here [Javascript - parse string to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447807/javascript-parse-string-to-long)
this link might be helpful for you.

Comment: This is more of comment then an answer. It does not answer OP question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `BigInt` type:

```
BigInt('90938498237058927340892374089');
```

It returns `BigInt` number with 'n'-literal:

```
90938498237058927340892374089n
```

Comment: There is a docs on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Have you tested this at all ? Does this answers OP's question ?