# bigInt to base2

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, binary, integer

I'd like to get for really big decimal values like e.g. `4.951760157141521e+27` to the matching **binaryString** using pure javaScript.

I'm aware that `4.951760157141521e+27` not really is a normal integer anymore what also leads to the problem that just using `toString(2)` does not work anymore.

```js
print = function(i) { console.log(i) }


let myDecimalNumber = 42;   
print(+myDecimalNumber.toString(2));

let myDecimalNumberBIG = 4.951760157141521e+27;   
print(+myDecimalNumberBIG.toString(2));
```

**How can I fix this?** My idea was to use something like a `bigInt` library but it seems like currently I could not find any working solution so I would really appreciate a working example `:)`

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you're looking for?

Comment: 4.951760157141521e+27 as binary String like "10001010100101...." @WillardSolutions

Comment: Since a few days, chrome supports BigInts (`4n ** 27n`)

Comment: Sound good but is not really helpful in my case :) @JonasW.

Comment: So you want to convert 4.951760157141521e+27  to a base 2 number, correct?

Comment: Absolutely right. You got it @WillardSolutions

Comment: Check the discussion here; it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334494/converting-large-numbers-from-binary-to-decimal-and-back-in-javascript