# From BigInt to binary in JS

Tags: javascript, binary, bigint

I'm calling an external function that returns a very large int as an interpretation of a binary number. A real example would be this:

`output = 56904843415172010980318367264425014256050490817210830044164893489159338592392`

I'm trying to convert this number into binary using JavaScript with a function I found around, but since JavaScript only supports 64-bit numbers is not working. Is there any workaround or libraries to this?

The decimal-to-binary function I'm using:

```
function dec2bin(dec) {
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: Does this help you? [Ref_one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334494/converting-large-numbers-from-binary-to-decimal-and-back-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const input = '56904843415172010980318367264425014256050490817210830044164893489159338592392';
const binaryRepresentation = BigInt(input).toString(2);
console.log(binaryRepresentation);
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `BigInt(input).toString(2)` is all you need! (Assuming `input` is a string, as this answer also assumes.)

Comment: You are absolutely right (the answer was updated)